# Spring Security CSRF Filter Conflicting with Session Management on Login Page

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I'm adapting a project to use Spring Security CSRF protection, and I'm getting an interesting behavior. On my login page, if I refresh the page once, thrice, five times, etc. then when I put appropriate credentials in it kicks me out due to failing CSRF, but if I log in immediately or after two, four, six, etc. refreshes, I get in just fine.

I've made progress in why this is happening, but I cannot figure out how to remedy the problem. It seems that a new CSRF token is only being generated every **other** request even though I end up with a new session every request. Diving into the Spring logic has revealed that the following sequence of events is most likely happening:

1. I hit the page for the first request. The CSRF filter creates a token (T1) of the sort `SaveOnAccessCsrfToken`and adds this as a request attribute.
2. A new session (S1) is created.
3. The JSP renders, causing the token (T1) in the request to be called, and the `SaveOnAccessCsrfToken` saves the token to the session (S1).
4. I hit the page again. The CSRF filter still sees the old session (S1), and thus gets a `DefaultCsrfToken` out of the session and adds this (the old token - T1) to the request instead of creating a new one.
5. A new session (S2) is created.
6. The JSP renders, causing the token (T1) in the request to be called, but since it's a `DefaultCsrfToken`, nothing is added to the session (S2).
7. I hit the page again. The CSRF filter still sees the old session (S2), but since nothing was added, to that session, it creates a new token (T2) of the sort `SaveOnAccessCsrfToken`and adds this as a request attribute.
8. A new session (S3) is created.
9. The JSP renders, causing the token (T2) in the request to be called, and the `SaveOnAccessCsrfToken` saves the token to the session (S3).
10. I hit the page again. I'm sure you see by now how this repeats.

I would seem the solution would be to change when the session is created, but I can't figure out how to do that. Thoughts?

Using Spring 4.2.2 and Spring-Security 4.0.3

Here's the security XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />        
<http pattern="/WEB-INF/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/error/**" security="none" />
<!-- Other unrelated URLs -->

<!-- Configure Spring URL based Web Security  -->
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll"/>
    <!-- Other unrelated URLs -->

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/> 

    <form-login login-page="/login" 
                authentication-failure-url="/loginFailure?$general{login.fail.urlPostFix}" 
                default-target-url="/afterSuccessfulLogin"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" /> 

    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
            invalidate-session="false" 
            logout-success-url="/login" 
            logout-url="/logout" /> 

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?invalidSession=true" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
    <headers disabled="true" />
</http> 

<authentication-manager> 
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="adminSecurityService"> 
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider> 
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />
```

Comment: Why is it even creating a new session, do you have a custom login form or are you using the default Spring Security one? And which versions are you using exactly? 4.0.x (what is x in this case). And can you also add your spring security configuration (or what you have so far).

Comment: The new session creation is on the app server and I do have a custom login form. I added the other info above.

Comment: I know where the session is created but why? There already is a session and the cookie should be presented, or maybe the question is why is it invalided if there is a session? Assuming you are using JSP can you add `<%@ page session="false" %>` to your page, that way only Spring Security is creating sessions and not your JSP.

Comment: The session is created because it's a login page. One generally doesn't want to retain sessions on login pages because then you risk parameters from an old login bleeding into a new one. Adding session=false not only didn't fix it, but broke the login in new and exciting ways (that don't seem relevant here).

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue? How did you do it?